# Saving app data encrypted on the phone (Android)

Tags: android

What is the best practice for saving Android app data (like users' data - every user has SQL database with data of all the other users) on the phone in SQL database?
This is a public app (has been published on the Play Store) and I need to decide how to encrypt the data and where to save it on the phone in that way no one will be able to reach it (not the users, nor other apps)

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you should not store the data of every user of your app on every users phone. It will be difficult to maintain data consistency and more.

Secondly, take a look at [the security section of the android development guide](https://developer.android.com/design-for-safety#security). The "best way" depends on your exact use case.

Cryptography is a difficult and important topic. DO NOT just look for answers like "Do it with XY" and implement it without understanding the theory.

Maybe not the short, easy answer you were looking for, sorry.^^

Comment: I can't find any reference to encrypted DB. The data I save on the phone is for optimization and I need to manage it in SQL DB. But because this is data of users, it should be encrypted.